# How to use OkHttp3ClientHttpRequestFactory

Tags: android, spring, resttemplate

I'm working in an Android project with the Spring library, using RestTemplate and need to use an `OkHttp3ClientHttpRequestFactory` with my own okhttp3.OkHttpClient. The problem is that the `OkHttp3ClientHttpRequestFactory` is not recognized.

I've the following import for RestTemplate in build.gradle(app):

```
implementation "org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:2.0.0.M1"
```

Is some other import necessary for the `OkHttp3ClientHttpRequestFactory` implementation?

Answer (score 0):

The `OkHttp3ClientHttpRequestFactory` is from the `spring-web` dependency that it's added by the `spring-boot-starter-web`.

When using Spring Boot, you can use:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Or, without the Spring Boot dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```